# ScrollReveal.js will not run

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

I am trying to use the widely applauded ScrollReveal.js put together by Julian Lloyd ([ScrollReveal](https://scrollrevealjs.org/))

I have followed the instruction guide on the page as well as on other sites but but the script does not provide the desired effect, in fact, there is no effect.

I have added the following to make this work:

**Added the .js and initialized the script:**

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <title>Aries Sercon Lda - Accounting, Tax and Consulting in Mozambique - Home</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Aries Sercon is an established firm providing accounting, tax and human resource services in Mozambique">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="img/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scrollReveal.min.js"></script>  
        <script>
        window.sr = new scrollReveal();
        sr.reveal('#landing');
        sr.reveal('#checks');
        sr.reveal('#process');
        sr.reveal('#clients');
        sr.reveal('#footer');
        </script>
    </head>
```

**Added the reference for each element ("data-sr")**

```
    <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="checks" id="checks" data-sr>

With all these, it does not work. I have checked the path which is correct.
                <p class="promo center">We are an independent group of accountants and tax professionals based in Mozambique. We have been operating in the market for over 30 years, long enough to witness and be part of the incredible growth of the country.</br></br>

                Together we have helped small and large businesses, novices and even veterans in finding and setting up a space for them in Mozambique, and in doing so have developed an acute understanding of the country's changing business dynamics.</br></br>

                Mozambique has seen consistent growth through a decade-long trend strongly driven by the extractive industries and large infrastructure projects. However, opportunities exist for small and medium size business ventures. A long coastline and an ideal geographic location also make it attractive for investment and trade.</p>

                <a href="#process" class="smoothScroll"><img src="assets/arrow.svg" class="arrows" alt="Go down"></a>

            </div>



        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that using `data-sr` attribute is a valid way to use this plugin. I haven't found this attribute in the plugin's code (in version `3.1.4`).

Your code is not working because the elements that should "reveal" are not initialized.

Try to paste the following code in your document:

```
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('#checks');

// if you have other elements, add them like this
sr.reveal('#other-element');
sr.reveal('#another-element');
```

I've also created a fiddle for demo: https://jsfiddle.net/82n10mk4/.

Comment: I've added the other elements that should be revealed. Should I remove the `data-sr` or keep it?

Comment: Yes, you can remove it.